# VirtualHost apache always returns same website not subdomain

Tags: symfony, subdomain, virtualhost, centos6, apache2.2

I'm using apache 2.2.15,  in a virtual machine over CentOS 6, I have a symfony proyect working here and my boss want to load a wordpress website in the same server on a subdomain. 
Subdomain is not working, I've tried a lot of configurations, this is the last one used:

mysite.cl.conf (in /etc/httpd/conf.d folder)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/symfonyProyect/web
    ServerName mysite.cl
    ServerAlias mysite.cl

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/symfonyProyect_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/symfonyProyect_access.log combined

    <Location />
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . /app.php [L]
        </IfModule>
        DirectoryIndex app.php
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysubdomain.mysite.cl

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysubdomain

    <Directory /var/www/html/mysubdomain>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mysubdomain_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mysubdomain_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

my hosts file (in /etc folder)

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
myip  mysite.cl mysubdomain.mysite.cl
```

and my hosts.conf

```
multi on
```

when I try mysite.cl it shows the symfony website, but when I try mysubdomain.mysite.cl, it gives me the "`This site can't be reached`" or "`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`".

The if I delete the first VirtualHost block, it showsme the wordpress website ( even using `ServerName mysubdomain.mysite.cl`).
Am I missing some configuration or something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is a DNS one not one from Apache. You need to modify the hosts file on same machine you are trying to browse to `mysubdomain.mysite.cl`.

Open a command prompt/shell on the machine you are running your browser on and just run `ping mysubdomain.mysite.cl` if it works your browsing should work too. If you get a message something like `ping: unknown host mysubdomain.mysite.cl` (Linux) or `Ping request could not find host mysubdomain.mysite.cl` (Windows). then simply edit the hosts file on that system or get a DNS entry added to your name server.

Simply editing /etc/hosts on the server that Apache runs on doesn't cause all other hosts to be able to resolve a hostname to an IP address.

Comment: as you said, it was not an Apache problem, the system won´t allow wildcards in the a records